# I'm trying to swap two number using operator but not able to swap the number please help to solve

Tags: php

Here, I'm trying to swap the number using PHP but not able to swap.
How to solve that problem.

My Code :

```
<?php  
$a = 45;  
$b = 78;  
echo "Before swapping:<br><br>";  
echo "a =".$a."  b=".$b;  
echo "<br/><br/>";
// Swapping Logic  
$a=$a+$b;  
$b=$a-$b;  
$a=$a+$b;  
echo "After swapping:<br><br>";  
echo "a =".$a."  b=".$b;  
?>
```

I'm a beginner in php just learning about logic but getting exception so any body can help how to solve it?

Comment: This isn't about PHP - it's about logic: after you stored the sum, you still have access to the old `b` which you can use to resolve the old `a` from the sum, following that you lost the old `b` but you now have the old `a` that you can use to resolve the old `b` from the sum using the same method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please replace your code

```
// Swapping Logic  

   $a=$a+$b;  
   $b=$a-$b;  
   $a=$a+$b;
```

with

```
    $a=$a+$b;  
    $b=$a-$b;  
    $a=$a-$b;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also swap the variables this way:

```
list($a, $b) = array($b, $a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just minus it with the one u added or you can try creating another variable to temporarily store the other value while you swap. storing it on a temporary variable is how people usually do it as if you have done leet code , the bubble sort is a good practice for this kind of logic.

```
   $a=$a+$b; 
   $b=$a-$b;  
   $a=$a-$b;



// Swapping Logic  
$third = $a;  
$a = $b;  
$b = $third;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dereference in arrays in one line:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

[$b,$a] = [$a,$b];

echo $a,' ', $b;    // 2 1
```

Works as far back as PHP 7.1.0

Demo: https://3v4l.org/q62Zf#v7.1.0